# How do I deploy a web application with a background worker to AppHarbor?

Tags: appharbor

I have an application which contains a web application and a background worker.

I defined an AppHarbor.sln solution file, and included both projects. However, only the background worker gets deployed. Also, even the tests of the web application project seem to be ignored. I experimented with the project ordering in the solution file, but it's always the background worker that gets deployed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A free AppHarbor application only has a single worker associated by default. This can be either a background worker or a web worker (this is detected on the first successful build).

You probably just need to scale the number of web workers to 1 on the "Subscription" page, which will immediately trigger the deployment of the web application.

If the web application still isn't running you should check the build output to verify that it contains a web app.

Comment: Should the current build contain the web project and its tests, are is the build system ignoring them as a whole as long as I have only one worker? The build output isn't showing those two projects.

Comment: The build system is not affected by the workers associated with an application, so you can include or exclude projects and executables depending on your requirements. If you include a background worker and a web worker you'll be able to deploy both. All referenced test projects will also be executed.

Answer (score 0):

AppHarbor has a [FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions) which helps you troubleshoot problems like this. On your case I would recommend downloading the build output and verifying that everything is in order. Also feel free to contact AppHarbor support if you have any questions.